# Hudson: How to set cvs program location on different platforms?

Tags: cvs, hudson

Ex:
Windows: c:\cvs\bin\cvs
Aix: /tools/bin
Ubuntu: /storage/bin

Answer (score 0):

Under "Configure Hudson" at http://yourhost:8080/hudson/configure , there's a section headed CVS with a textbox labelled `cvs executable`.

Enter `cvs` in here and Hudson will look on your `PATH` (whether Windows or Linux) for cvs. Alternatively enter the full path here.

Answer (score 0):

Under http://yourhost:8080/computer/--nodename--/configure you can set environment variables and tool locations on a per-node basis.

Unfortunately, the cvs scm implementation doesn't seem to use this feature at the moment, so having the cvs executable in the path on each slave is the best option.